# Nircmd | Setting Volume | set specified volume amount (*/100)

Tags: windows, command-line, windows-10, audio, nircmd

Nircmd is like a variable to windows already built-in cmd and comes along with great informative, most especially brief documentation.

> ## SETTING VOLUME (commands)
>
> ```
> changesysvolume
> ```
>
> - change volume via integer-amount with only options to increase / decrease from the last set volume amount on the os-level.
>
> ```
> changesysvolume2
> ```
>
> - same as the first command, but you're able to specify specific channels (*left / right*)

Well, for my purpose I'll be using the first one `changesysvolume`, the problem is... is that there is no way to set a *specified* volume amount. For my case, I want to be able to set my *default volume device* to `75/100`

### Notes

- My System is Windows 10 x64 (Home Premium)
- Preferably, I would prefer to use built-in methods via `cmd` parameters that's already within Windows 10.

Comment: Isn't that what I said? If my answer is correct, then the typical action is to mark the answer as the answer. If you edit your question, the question is still viewed by the system as open and unanswered.

Comment: yes this post is [SOLVED] using mobile right now, there seems to be no option  to mark as solved. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to set the volume to a specific level and not add/subtract from the existing volume level. Use a different parameter called `setsysvolume`.

[NirCMD setsysvolume](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/nircmd.html):

Set the volume to the highest value: `nircmd.exe setsysvolume 65535`

If you multiply 65535 with 0.75 you get 49151:

`nircmd.exe setsysvolume 49151`